# Import .3ds file into Roomle

Tags: 3dsmax, fbx, roomle

How do I import a 3ds max model with materials into Roomle using the .fbx format?

When I do an export from 3d studio max and upload it in the admin interface the model does not contain any materials/textures.

I already tried to use the `embed media` option when exporting the `.fbx` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to create the texture as a physical material instead of a standard surface material. I got this idea from the samples in the [docs](https://docs.roomle.com/web/datamanagement/#sample-products-and-files). I downloaded the [`lounge chair.fbx` zip](https://catalog.roomle.com/samples/Lounge_Chair_fbx.zip) to see how your files looked, so that helped.